# Are Vrata (व्रत), and Upavāsa (उपवास) the same thing, or some difference exists? Is there any esoteric explanation?

Tags: belief, fasting, vrata, upasana

Generally we use both these terms interchangeably:

> Vrata (व्रत)
>
> Upvasa (उपवास)

But, sometimes I feel there must be a difference, even if a minute one.

Like we famously refer Pitāmaha Bhīṣma as DevaVrata (देवव्रत), and not DevaUpavāsa (देव-उपवास).

From the perspective of a native Hindi speaker, Vrata seems more connected with an oath/vow - physical level, while Upavāsa sounds more related to internal and metaphysical vows, like we say 'Upāsanā (उपासना)'.

#### So, please explain if any difference exists between Vrata and Upavāsa.

**Also, what's the esoteric significance of Vrata/Upavāsa?**

It cannot just only mean - 'not eating food', because ways and rituals of Hinduism extends not just to physical, but mental, metaphysical and transcendental levels of explanations too.